# Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in

Tags: php, chmod

Ok I have a php file that allows me to upload a csv file, read in the data, and output whatever I need. I'm having trouble on the file uploading part.

Here is my code in it's entirety:

```
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/tmp/");
# chmod(UPLOAD_DIR, 0777);
// show upload form
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
?>
<em>GoCode Upload.</em>

<form action="gocode.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
<?php
}
// process file upload
else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];
    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
        #exit;
    }

    // ensure a safe filename
    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);
    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }
    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"], UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
    if (!$success) {
        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
        #exit;
    }
    // set proper permissions on the new filei

    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0777);
    echo "<p>Uploaded file saved as " . $name . ".</p>";
}

$fh = fopen(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 'r'); // 1
$minutes = 0;
$cost = 0;
if ($fh) { // 2
  while ( ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false ) { // 3
    //print_r($row); // 4
$minutes += $row[0];
$cost += $row[1];
    //echo '<br>';


        }
}
echo "Minutes: ";
echo number_format((float)$minutes, 2, '.', '');
echo '<BR>';
echo "Cost: $";
echo number_format((float)$cost, 2, '.', '');
echo '<BR><BR><BR>';
```

Then I get this error:

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/report/gocode.php on line 56

where line 56 in my code is :

```
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0777);
```

I originally had permissions at 0644, but moved to 0777 to see if that worked and it didn't. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: line 55, add: echo UPLOAD_DIR . $name; Run the script, see what the output is. The output is obviously not correct, use bugfixing to see if a) the upload happened, b) the address is right

Comment: Ok when I add that in, it gives the right directory: `/tmp/2016-01-19_00-00-00__00_2016-01-19_23-59-59__00.csv` where that long file name is the name of the file I am uploading....